Next.js 14 use yt-dlp and send to the client whatever yt-dlp has downloaded
I'm working on a Next.js project that includes yt-dlp inside and I'm not sure how do I actually do it
I've tried pretty much a ton of stuff, going through reddit, stackoverflow, etc. but none of them were relevant to my search. You guys could walkthrough me tho, whether if that means you know how to use wget or curl for sending from server to the client, I would appreciate it if you guys used the API Route instead /app/api/handleDownload/route.ts.

You are asking for help, but there is no code here. How can we guess what the content of your app is?  Please create  a [mre]
